# mathieu function of non integer order asymptotics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

I have an asymptotic expression for the integer mathieu functions:
$se_\nu(q,z)$ and $ce_\nu(q,z)$, where $\nu$ is an integer. I would like to use these expression for the case $\nu$ real. My question is, is there some way to represent a non-integer mathieu function using integer ones?

thank you.